Can I use simple slopes with AFT models?
I am doing a study using accelerated failure time (AFT) log-normal models to predict survival time for a new incarceration (couldn't use Cox PH as the proportional hazards assumption was violated). There are a couple of interactions in the model between a binary variable (presence/absence of a specific mental health diagnosis) and two continuous variables 1) number os visits received, 2) number of misconduct instances recorded. Specifically, all models explore if the presence of the clinical diagnosis affects time to recidivism and include 9 control variables:

Model 1 - diagnosis --> new incarceration (main effects model no interactions)
Model 2 - includes 1st interaction diagnosis*number of visits
Model 3 - includes 2nd interaction diagnosis*number of misconduct events.

One of my co-authors is suggesting simple slopes to better look at the interactions.
I have been searching for a while now can't seem to find a way to use simple slopes with AFT models - all studies I found that use both usually do simple slopes after an simple regression and then move onto the AFT modeling.
Any suggestions/advice?
Thank you!!

Please edit the question to say more about the data, the model, and the interactions you included. In particular, the number of re-incarcerations might limit how well you can evaluate the interactions if there are many other predictors in the model. Also: Are the interactions between 2 continuous variables, or between a categorical and a continuous variable? How well did the AFT model fit the data, and which AFT model family did you use?

There should be no problem with using simple slopes (outcome estimates as a function of a continuous predictor at specified levels of an interacting predictor). You just have to use appropriate post-modeling software tools, like those provided by the R emmeans package, to get model estimates and confidence intervals at specified combinations of predictor values. That package is used in the first simple-slopes example on this web book; a package vignette also shows how to proceed.
Those examples are for a standard linear regression model, but the package can accept accelerated failure time models from the R survreg() function. That's illustrated on this page (which also shows a way to evaluate the quality of your log-normal fit).
With an accelerated failure time model, what you get most directly for an estimated outcome will be the linear predictor value (related to the acceleration factor) as a function of the continuous predictor; that's the scale that the post-modeling software uses to get confidence intervals. That should be OK to show on its own, although you might be able to ask the software to re-express the results as some function of that linear predictor value.
I strongly recommend, however, that you do not use 3 separate models. To avoid omitted-variable bias, it's best practice to work with a single comprehensive model. In your situation that would include all of the control variables, the diagnosis, and both of the interactions with diagnosis that you are evaluating separately now.
Also, number of visits and number of misconduct events might not have strictly linear associations with outcome, as your simple interaction term implies. Consider more flexible modeling of those predictors. Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies is a valuable resource, with Chapter 2 showing how to deal with non-linear associations with outcome, Chapter 4 outlining principles of regression modeling, and Chapters 18 and 19 discussing parametric survival models.
